# Difference in executing shell script by 'sh' and 'source' (and '.')

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a tiny question.
When I execute my shell file by '**sh**', it works differently.
(it printed '-e')

Google says "Check your first line(#!/bin/bash) and 'env | grep sh'"
But there no do difference in my eyes...
Would you tell me why it is?

+++
I tried changing '#!/bin/bash' → '#!/bin/dash', but noting changed.

Thanks for reading..

**[my first code(first.sh)] -bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "hi"
```

**[run script and result]**

```
# . first.sh
Hi
# source first.sh
Hi
```

```
# sh first.sh
-e hi
```

**[my second code(second.sh)] -dash**

```
#!/bin/dash
echo -e "hi"
```

**[run script and result]**
nothing change...

**[OS]**
ubuntu 18.04

**[environment]**

```
# env | grep sh
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

```
# ll /bin | grep sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1113504  6월  6  2019 bash*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  121432  1월 25  2018 dash*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4  6월  6  2019 rbash -> bash*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4  7월 18  2019 sh -> dash*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4  7월 18  2019 sh.distrib -> dash*
```

Comment: Please prefer paste code than image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What does ls -l /usr/bin/sh return?

Comment: @Raman Sailopal
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/sh': No such file or directory ....

Comment: @YNam : Please also post the full command you used to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

that is because the `sh` shell interpreter does not recognize `-e` as a flag and prints it as a regular string.

`source` and `.` use your `SHELL` env, which is `bash`, whom recognizes the `-e` flag and does not treat it as a string.